# Replace words in a text using a Python dictionary (replace the key with its value)

Tags: python

I need to replace words in a text using a Python dictionary, replace the key word with its value word, (exemple : replace "d" by "de")
my code doesn't work...

Do you have an idea ? Thanks a lot !

```
with open("littlestory.txt", 'r', encoding='utf8') as descriptor:
    lines = descriptor.readlines()
    def cleaning(text):
        for line in lines:
            line = line.replace('-', ' ')
            my_dict = {
                'd':'de',
                's':'se',
                'l':'le',
                'j':'je',
                'n':'ne',
                'c':'ce'
            }
        for key, value in my_dict.items():
            lines = lines.replace(key, value)
            lineclean = ''.join(caractere for caractere in ligne if caractere not in string.punctuation)
            print(lineclean)
    cleaning(text)
```

Comment: You never do anything with the file you read. Start with calling `cleaning(lines)`.

Comment: Here the problem is clear but generally: Explain "doesn't work". What happens, what should happen? Show an error message (if any) completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Thanks Friedrich and Michael, here's error message

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[276], line 18
     16         lineclean = ''.join(caractere for caractere in ligne if caractere not in string.punctuation)
     17         print(lineclean)
---> 18 cleaning(text)

Comment: Cell In[276], line 4, in cleaning(text)
      3 def cleaning(text):
----> 4     for line in lines:
      5         line = line.replace('-', ' ')
      6         my_dict = {
      7             'd':'de',
      8             's':'se',
   (...)
     12             'c':'ce'
     13         }

UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'lines' where it is not associated with a value

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in your code. You'll need to fix those before you can test its functionality. You might also want to take a look at *str.translate*

Answer (score 1):

The Python *str* object has a built-in *translate* function. You can use *str.maketrans* to define how the translation should be implemented.

Using that technique, your code can be reduced to:

```
my_dict = {"d": "de", "s": "se", "l": "le", "j": "je", "n": "ne", "c": "ce"}

translator = str.maketrans(my_dict)

with open("littlestory.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as descriptor:
    for line in map(str.rstrip, descriptor):
        print(line.translate(translator))
```